# Is Hemangioma treatable by medicine?

Tags: removal, plastic-surgery, cosmetics, lips

I am a 45 year old male from India. I was born with a Hemangioma in upper lip. Doctors told us it does not have a complete cure, so they planned to give injections when it increased.

Doctors are now planning to decrease it with injection and then treat by surgery.
Is there any alternate procedure preferably with orally administered medicines?

Answer (score 0):

Oral beta blockers used successfully fit infantile form. 
Pulsed dye laser increasingly popular, though not sure if this is an option for you.

Comment: Sure. Surgeon is thinking options, I'll try to discuss with him. He is an MRCS and a former faculty with [PGIMER](http://pgimer.edu.in/PGIMER_PORTAL/PGIMERPORTAL/home.jsp) . Some local friend told some intravenous solution should be there. Lets see how it goes.

Comment: Recently I was done one Sclerotherapy i'd update its result after 3 months..

Comment: Doctors  giving Sclerotherapy  said it's improving and would continue for next 1-2 yrs.